# How to find the css selector of a href/a/button

Tags: css-selectors

I am trying to find out css selector for "Clear" button, as mentioned in below script:

```
<a href="" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral search-button"
                             ng-click="vm.clearFilter()" style="">Clear</a>
```

I have tried :

1. `a[href*="Clear"]`
2. `a:contains('Clear')`
3. `a[*'Clear'*]`

I am expecting to get a click on "Clear" button.

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to reach that button with the text, then it's not possible.
How about putting an id:

```css
a#clearButton{
   background:red
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="clearButton" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral 
               search-button">Clear</a>
```

I see you use AngularJS, the id can be added via the code

Comment: I am using this code while automating an application, so as an automation engineer, won't be able to ask this change just for my convenience, anyway thanks, I will try it through other selectors.

Comment: Are classes re-used?  if not you may can use a.class ? Or a[href=""] ?